# Custom localize refactoring with context action in C# using ReSharper 8.2 SDK

Tags: c#, xml, resharper, resharper-8.0, resharper-sdk

Localization in our .NET 4.0 C# project is basically the following:

1. `MyCompany.Resources.dll` contains two RESX files: `A.resx` and `B.resx` with their localized counterparts (`A_de.resx`, `B_hu.resx`, etc.). These files consist of the usual RESX xml elemens, like `<data name="key" xml:space="preserve"><value>value</value></data>`
2. `MyCompany.Common.dll` contains a public (singleton) class `MyCompanyResourceManager` with two methods for accessing the localized values in `A.resx` and `B.resx` by key, like `GetA(string key)` and `GetB(string key)`.
3. Wherever there is a string in the C# code that needs to be localized, we *manually* open either `A.resx` or `B.resx` with XML editor (the Visual Studio resource editor screws up something in the xml), add a new `<data>` tag to the XML document with a new key, and in the C# code we *manually* replace the string with a call to `MyCompanyResourceManager.Instance.GetA(...)` (or `GetB(...)`).

This work can be speeded up with code snippets and live templates in ReSharper, but I feel a need for a better solution for this "workflow" (and not for the localization mechanism, that cannot be changed :) ). That's why a want to write a ReSharper plugin that does the repetitive parts. What I would like to achieve:

- When the caret is on a string literal in the C# code, offer context actions `Localize in A` and `Localize in B`
- When I choose either of them, popup a dialog to prompt the key to be used in the RESX from the user
- Place the new `<data>` tag in the corresponding RESX file and replace the string literal with the call the appropriate method. Import the namespace of the `MyCompanyResourceManager` class if needed, and reference its assembly, if needed. (Referencing the assembly is not a must, because it can be assumed that `MyCompany.Common` is referenced everywhere)
- open the chosen RESX file to see the changes

Optional features (to make plugin more widely usable):

- settings page to specify the RESX files (even more than two), the corresponding method calls, and the class that contains these methods
- before prompting the key, search in the chosen RESX file for the string literal, just in case it is already localized

My problems / questions:

- I'm kind of lost in the [ReSharper SDK reference](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/ReSharper+8+Plugin+Development) and in its incomplete documentation, so a comprehensive material / tutorial on the available classes / interfaces would be great (if there is any)
- How to open a project / solution file in Visual Studio with the ReSharper API?
- How to manipulate XML files with the ReSharper API? The sample context action is a reverse string thing, so accessing the literal under the caret is OK.
- Should I use a context action or a refactoring for this scenario?
- How to start a refactoring from a context action?
- Where to start, what should be well understood of the API for this task?

Thanks in advance!